# How to make sure a thread gets the most recent variables modified by another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Ok, so I am making a 2D game, and all the map is represented in a 2D Array. I have this huge methods that modifies the map based on what is already in the map. So after a while implementing features, the FPS is lowering, so I decided to try to use multiple threads to make it faster ( Good thing, no? ).

I made 3 Threads to do the work, one that paints and handles Events, one that updates the base part of the map and the other updates another set of variables. The problem is, it paints but it does not update when I start all 3 Threads. It does update when I call the methods from the painting thread. I tested the first updating thread by adding "System.exit(0);" at the run, and it did not started when it otherwise would start. I also tried to manually change a tile of the map directly in the run method of the Updating thread, but it did nothing. So I concluded the run is executed, and the variables are modified. So I thought that maybe the variables used by the painter aren't the updated ones.

All the variables are in a seperated class and are static ( Was that right? ) and were accessed by an object, but then I changed it to 'Direct' Access ( IDE Suggestion ) with the code "nameOfTheClass.variableName"

Almost forgot to mention, the Events ( In the class with the paint() method ) modifies the Map, and this part does work.

I don't know what to do, anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is a race condition instead. The variable modification may be 'delayed' (by a few hundred nanoseconds?) as other accesses go through, but it will still happen, eventually. In this case, I don't think `volatile` or anything like that will make a difference, since the ordering of thread syncs should not be important. If it is, you have bigger things to worry about. Also, I think your terminology might be a bit messed up --I can't really understand the threading issue in relation to your code.

If you need hard synchronisation, you can establish resource 'fences' (synchronization blocks) and keep your resource accesses within these fences, so that race conditions cannot occur. You establish transactions by nature of the fact that nothing can get into the fence while you are operating on these variables.

Comment: My termonology IS messed up alot.
The problem is that the paint method doesn't paint the variables that were modified by the update method, it seem to paint the default ones, or the ones modified within the same class

Comment: Also, I'm not sure your game is complex enough to warrant multi-threading. Additionally, event processing certainly does not warrant a separate thread -- these are usually callbacks, so you set a structure with the event details and pick it up on the main event loop (maybe a command queue).

Comment: Events does not have a seperated thread, they just are in the same class as the paint() method. Also, do you know a better way to increase the performances of a 2D game? I'm running at 30 FPS with a low amount of features, so it will get laggiers. I've seen similar games doing 3 times more then what I am doing at 60 FPS in C ( I KNOW it's not the same but the point is that there should be a way to make this faster )

Comment: I'd probably advise suing a higher level Java2D game framework if you're going that route (http://www.interactivepulp.com/pulpcore/, http://www.13thmonkey.org/~boris/jgame/), or use Slick2D (http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) which is LWJGL (OpenGL)-based :)

The main issue will be drawing speed from having to redraw the entire game screen 60 times a second. It's slow, but can be sped up by only redrawing dirty regions. However, it's complex for novices, whereas higher-level libs can do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark the offending variable as `volatile`, which will prevent the compiler from caching a copy in a local variable, instead reading/writing the actual value each time.